# Magento 2 - sales_order_place_after not returning Order ID

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, place-order

I have created an event for `sales_order_place_after` event.

This doesn't return Order Id. However, it returns Increment ID

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();       
        $order->getIncrementId();
        $order->getId();
    }
```

Comment: Try to dump out the order data `var_dump($order->getData())`

Comment: No, it is not working .

Comment: Try to die `var_dump($order->getData()); die();`.

Comment: Try with $order->getEntityId();

Comment: @Rakesh,@Khoa- it is not working.

Comment: you can use sales_order_save_after event to get order id

Comment: where would the result will show on admin order or when customer placed an order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Magento 2 observer I used this code, you get the order data like this,

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class YOUROBSERVERCLASS implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderFactory)
    {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $lastorderId = $orderIds[0];

        $order = $this->orderFactory->load($lastorderId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't get orderId with that code using `sales_order_place_after`. From what I find that event triggers before order saved to DB. PlaceAfterPlugin from Phil Schmidt answer, works just fine. `checkout_submit_all_after` observer also works fine.

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question but given I have just faced the same problem myself I thought I would give my take on the answer. `sales_order_place_after` is triggered before the order is saved to db so at the point your code is running the order entity ID doesn't exist. There are few options to work around this:

You could use `sales_order_save_after` which is triggered after the order is actually persisted to db. This will allow you to have access to the order ID. This approach has risks however as it can be triggered again after the order is created. If you only want to run your code only once when the order is first placed, using this observer may have unexpected side effects.

Alternatively rather than using an observer you could create a plugin around `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::place`. This will allow you to do what I suspect you are trying to do with `sales_order_place_after`.

As a rough example your modules `etc/di.xml` would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="my-module-order-service" type="My\Module\Plugin\OrderServicePlugin" sortOrder="5"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And your plugin class like this:

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin;

class OrderServicePlugin
{
    public function aroundPlace(\Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $subject, \Closure $proceed,  \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $return = $proceed($order);

        $orderId = $order->getEntityId();

        // your custom code

        return $return;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is better to avoid around plugin unless necessary . Use after plugin or Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::place

etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
        <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface">
            <plugin name="MyOrderPlaceAfterPlugin" type="My\Module\Plugin\Order\PlaceAfterPlugin" sortOrder="99" />
        </type>
    </config>
```

My\Module\Plugin\Order\PlaceAfterPlugin.php

```
//namespace My\Module\Plugin\Order;

class  PlaceAfterPlugin {


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagementInterface
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor $order
     * @return $order
     */
    public function afterPlace(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagementInterface , $order)
    {
        $orderId = $order->getId();

        // do something with order object (Interceptor )

       return $order;
    }
}
```