# Executing Custom script after placing the order successfully magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order

Custom php script should be executed after placing the order or after performing the place order action in one page checkout page. What is the best way to do this operation or action. Should i create Custom Observer or controller?

Comment: Please check this link it will help for you, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152350/magento-2-sales-order-place-after-not-returning-order-id

Comment: did you make a custom script?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use event.**

> Use the event checkout_submit_all_after

**this event provide u current  place order and it quote object**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_submit_all_after',
    [
        'order' => $order,
        'quote' => $this->getQuote()
    ]
);
```

As you want to strick the your observer at frontend

So,define the event on

```
app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/frontent/events.xml
```

**code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="checkout_submit_all_after_add_andfetch" instance="{vendorname}\{Modulename}\Observer\CheckoutSubmit" />
    </event>
</config>
```